# Init reference members using crtp

Tags: c++, crtp

Is there a way to init references using CRTP?

My goal is to make something like following code to work

```
#include <iostream>

int gI = 1;

template <typename Derived>
struct A
{
    A()
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->InitRefs();
    }

    void InitInt(int & i) { i = gI; }
};

struct B : public A<B>
{
    B() : A<B>() {}

    void InitRefs()
    {
        InitInt(i);
    }

    int & i;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    std::cout << b.i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Reference members must be initialized in a *mem-initializer-list*, and (like all references) cannot be reseated.

If you want the base class template to provide reference member initializers, consider supplying member functions that return an lvalue reference to `int`:

```
template <typename Derived>
struct A {
    int& InitInt() { return gI; }
};

struct B : public A<B> {
    B() : A<B>(), i(InitInt()) {}
    int & i;
};
```

Otherwise, if you're committed to the current design, consider using `std::reference_wrapper<int>`, which behaves like a reference in limited ways and can be reseated:

```
template <typename Derived>
struct A {
    A() {}
    void InitInt(std::reference_wrapper<int> & i) { i = gI; }
};

struct B : public A<B> {
    B() : A<B>() { InitRefs(); }
    void InitRefs() { InitInt(i); }
    std::reference_wrapper<int> i;
};
```

Note that you cannot call `InitRefs` from the base class constructor, as the derived class object does not exist until its constructor body is entered.